# How to navigate from one view to another view from viewmodel in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, view, viewmodel

I have one ViewModel and two Views. How can I navigate to View2 from ViewModel. I read somewhere that  we need to use PRISM, for opening multiple Views from ViewModel in Silverlight. Is there any alternative for PRISM?

Comment: What do you mean by 'open a view'? Do you wish to just navigate there or what?

Comment: Yes! Navigate from one view to another view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you do not want to use view logic in your viewmodel. Your viewmodel should not know anything about the view. It would be a better idea for your viewmodel to set a property letting the view know it's time to navigate.
Here's an example:

**ViewModel**:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ViewModels
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null) return;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private bool _DoneDoingStuff;
        public bool DoneDoingStuff
        {
            get
            {
                return _DoneDoingStuff;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_DoneDoingStuff != value)
                {
                    _DoneDoingStuff = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("DoneDoingStuff");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<navigation:Page
    x:Class="Views.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModels">
    <navigation:Page.Resources>
        <vm:MyViewModel
            x:Key="MyViewModelInstance" />
    </navigation:Page.Resources>
    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutRoot"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyViewModelInstance}}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:DataTrigger
                Binding="{Binding DoneDoingStuff}"
                Value="True">
                <ei:HyperlinkAction
                    NavigateUri="AnotherPage.xaml" />
            </ei:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Grid>
</navigation:Page>
```

- Use a `DataTrigger` with `Binding` property set to the `DoneDoingStuff` property from your viewmodel, and the `Value` property set to "True". The `DataTrigger` will trigger when `DoneDoingStuff` from your viewmodel is set to true.
- Now you need a trigger action to navigate. Use `HyperlinkAction` with the `NavigateUri` property set to the page you're navigating to.
- Be sure to have **System.Windows.Interactivity**, **System.Windows.Controls.Navigation**, and **Microsoft.Expression.Interactions** assemblies in your references.

At first, this might seem to be too much, but your view logic is now where it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use PRISM, but it might be best.

One way that I have done it (and it is sloppy) is to have a MainView page that has a Navigation frame in it that will load the first view on start up. The MainView has to be a Page and not a UserControl. You need to have a navigation frame with uri mappings in the xaml and have a frame declared as shared/static in the code behind of the MainView Page and then set the loaded event (in the xaml) of the frame like so:

```
Public Shared MainContentFrame As Frame
Private Sub MainContentFrameXaml_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    MainContentFrame = TryCast(sender, Frame)
End Sub
```

Then in the viewmodel you can just call:

```
MainView.MainContentFrame.Navigate(New Uri("/SecondView", UriKind.Relative))
```

This probably violates the MVVM pattern in some way and may not be a good way to do it, but it works. This is how I used to do it, now I use PRISM.

Comment: @user672094   Mark my answer as the answer if it helped... I love the rep!