# WPF MVVM navigate views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

I have a WPF application with multiple views. I want to switch from view 1 to view 2 and from there I can switch to multiple views. So I want a button on view 1 that loads view2 in the same window.

I tried those things, but can't get it to work.

- [How to navigate through windows with MVVM Light for WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9290269/mvvm-light-toolkit-galasoft-for-wpf-navigation-through-windows)
- https://galasoft.ch/posts/2011/01/navigation-in-a-wp7-application-with-mvvm-light

From the first link, the problem is that I don't understand the ViewModelLocator code. They call the `CreateMain();` function but where is this defined, and how can I switch to another view from inside a view.

Comment: @AndrasSebö, on this occasion, I disagree with you. While I accept that this is not a great question, I have seen much worse and I believe that it is quite clear what the user is after.

Comment: Well the question is: How can i switch the view from inside a view.

Comment: Did you find a good way to address this issue?

Comment: I ended up with using the magellan framework. It's a great framework for apps with a lot of navigation.

Comment: @user2499088, please put that into an answer, perhaps with a few more lines and then accept it as the correct answer, so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 129):

Firstly, you don't need any of those toolkits/frameworks to implement MVVM. It can be as simple as this... let's assume that we have a `MainViewModel`, and `PersonViewModel` and a `CompanyViewModel`, each with their own related view and each extending an `abstract` base class `BaseViewModel`.

In `BaseViewModel`, we can add common properties and/or `ICommand` instances and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. As they all extend the `BaseViewModel` class, we can have this property in the `MainViewModel` class that can be set to any of our view models:

```
public BaseViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
```

Of course, you'd be implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface correctly on *your* properties unlike this quick example. Now in `App.xaml`, we declare some simple `DataTemplate`s to connect the views with the view models:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PersonViewModel}">
    <Views:PersonView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CompanyViewModel}">
    <Views:CompanyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, wherever we use one of our `BaseViewModel` instances in our application, these `DataTemplate`s will tell the framework to display the related view instead. We can display them like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
```

So all we need to do now to switch to a new view is to set the `ViewModel` property from the `MainViewModel` class:

```
ViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
```

Finally, how do we change the views from other views? Well there are several possible ways to do this, but the easiest way is to add a `Binding` from the child view directly to an `ICommand` in the `MainViewModel`. I use a custom version of the `RelayComand`, but you can use any type you like and I'm guessing that you'll get the picture:

```
public ICommand DisplayPersonView
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => ViewModel = new PersonViewModel(), 
        canExecute => !IsViewModelOfType<Person>()); }
}
```

In the child view XAML:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DisplayPersonView, RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MainView}}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

That's it! Enjoy.

Comment: I think this will work. But when i do ViewModel = new ... i get the error "ViewModel is a property, but is used as a type"

Comment: Did you set the type of the `ViewModel` property to `BaseViewModel` and do your view models all extend that class?

Comment: Well i use MVVM Light so its all set to ViewModelBase, but all the viewmodels extend that class, and the property has the type ViewModelBase

Comment: Well if you're using MVVM Light, then you should probably stick to whatever they use to do these things... my point was that you don't *need* to use a framework to implement this functionality.

Comment: @Sheridan 
Such an inspiring approach! How did you implement the x:Type ViewModels and the Views that you used in the DataTemplate defined in the app.xaml?

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand your question @ETG87. The view model classes are just classes that extend the `BaseViewModel` class and the views are just `UserControl`s.

Comment: @Sheridan I put the following inside <Application.Resources>:
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type BaseViewModel:MainWindowViewModel}">
            <Views:MainWindow />
        </DataTemplate>
I get following errors:
The namespace prefix "BaseViewModel" is not defined. 
The namespace prefix "Views" is not defined.
I hope that makes sense. Edit, I solved the 1st error, I forgot that I must reference my namespace.

Comment: Dude, you need to read up about [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086(v=vs.110).aspx)... my views are declared in a `AppName.Views` namespace which has a mapped XAML Namespace Prefix of `Views`. The view models are declared in a `AppName.ViewModels` namespace and therefore mapped to a XAML Namespace Prefix of `ViewModels`. There should be no `BaseViewModel` namespace because that is a class, not a namespace.

Comment: My bad, @Sheridan, thanks for the link. I got it working now. Your the man.

Comment: @Sheridan, I do this in my application but even though I create a new instance of the ViewModel in my code, the XAML code creates another instance. Is there any way to get around this? I'm trying to switch the view and immediately bind to an event but since the XAML creates a new instance, I can't make it happen.

Comment: Or is there a way to send parameters using this method?

Comment: @DoctorOreo, please ask a new question, linking to this one if you like. If you use my '@' name as you did in the above comment, I will be notified and can answer there, where there will be more space.

Comment: @Sheridan I've been trying to follow this, and I believe I'm missing something trivial. I've posted a new question here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849784/wpf-navigation-using-mvvm.  Perhaps you could take a look at point me in the right direction?

Comment: Anyone found a way to adapt this to Windows 8.1 "universal" app?  DataTemplate no longer supports "DataType" ?

Comment: @AUSTX_RJL, if you haven't already, you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: Excellent approach @Sheridan .  Is there a way to switch the views from inside the child view usercontrol ViewModel? How can I call my mainviewmodel from child viewmodel .

Comment: @Gopichandar, you can use a `delegate` to signal the `MainViewModel` from a child view model. See my answer to the [How to call functions in a main view model from other view models?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522202/how-to-call-functions-in-a-main-view-model-from-other-view-models/19522419#19522419) question for an example of how to do this.

Comment: It's not finding my ancestor from the `RelativeSource` part. I'm pretty positive everything is named correctly, too. Any help with this?

Comment: Sorry @JonathanTuzman, but this is not the place to ask a new question. You can link to this question in your new question though, if that helps.

Answer (score 8):

When i first started wiht MVVM I also struggled with the different MVVM-frameworks and especially the navigation part. Therefore I use this little tutorial i found, that Rachel Lim has created. It's very nice and well explained.

Have a look at it on the following link:

- http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/

Hope it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i mean. I used this example for another application, but for this application i dont have a sidemenu. So i have a button on view1 and when i click on that button it has to switch to view2

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2011/08/27/mefedmvvm-navigationextension/) link will help you. Just set the `NavigateTo` property to the view which you need to display on the window.

As an example you can do something like

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindowView" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                                 xmlns:meffed="http:\\www.codeplex.com\MEFedMVVM"
                                 meffed:ViewModelLocator.NonSharedViewModel="YourViewModel"
                                 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Button meffed:NavigationExtensions.NavigateTo="firstview"
                    meffed:NavigationExtensions.NavigationHost="{Binding ElementName=_viewContainer}"
                    meffed:NavigationExtensions.NavigateOnceLoaded="False"
                    Visibility="Visible" />

    <ContentControl x:Name="_viewContainer" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
<Window>
```

Then the class file would be

```
public partial class MainWindowView : Window
{
    public MainWindowView()
    {           
              InitializeComponent();
    }

        public ContentControl ViewContainer { get { return _viewContainer; } }

    }
```

Then you can define each view as `UserControl` and then using the link I gave above bind the button's `meffed:NavigationExtensions.NavigateTo="secondView"`. To target the `ContentControl` of the `Window` just use a `RelativeSource` binding. For e.g

`meffed:NavigationExtensions.NavigationHost="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},Path=ViewContainer}"`

In each of the view just see that you annotate the code behind class definition with the `[NavigationView("firstview")]` and so on.

It is complicated for first time but it will be very easy once you understand the idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ContentControl x:Name="K.I.S.S" Content="{Binding ViewModel, Converter={StaticResource ViewLocator}}"/>
```