# Using ContentControl to display views in WPF doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, navigation

I am currently working on a small project by myself to learn WPF better, and a question I was asking myself is how would navigation between different views work if I want to follow the MVVM pattern.

I have stumbled upon [this question here answering my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views), but unfortunately it does not seem to work. Instead of having my view display, it is only the namespace of the associated viewmodel that is displayed. So, for exemple, instead of seeing my LoginView, I am seeing a white screen with "JollyFinance.ViewModels.LoginViewModel" written.

Here is my MainWindow.xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Different pages -->
     <DataTemplate x:Key="LoginView" DataType="vm:LoginViewModel">
        <views:LoginView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>
</Grid>
```

Here is my MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableObject
{
    private ViewModelNavigationBase _currentViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    }

    public ViewModelNavigationBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel != value)
            {
                _currentViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My LoginViewModel.cs file:

```
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(Login);
        NavigateCommand = new RelayCommand(Login);
    }

    private void Login(object param)
    {
        Popup codePopup = new Popup();
        TextBlock popupText = new TextBlock();
        popupText.Text = "Test";
        popupText.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
        popupText.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;
        codePopup.Child = popupText;
    }

    public String Username { get; set; }

    public String Password { get; set; }

    public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
}
```

My LoginView.xaml file is a `UserControl` comprised of a few `Buttons` and `TextBlocks`. `BindableObject` is just an abstract class that I use that implements the `INotifyProperty` interface. And `ViewModelNavigationBase` is the class that all my viewmodels will inherit from; it doesn't contain anything for the moment.

How would I resolve this issue for it to display my view instead of a string representation of the associated viewmodel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have finally found what the problem was. For some reason, when you declare x:Key on the DataTemplate, it made the ContentControl Content appear as a string. I have removed the x:Key of the DataTemplate and everything works now. I also had to apply nemesv's answer for it to work.

Before:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LoginView" DataType="vm:LoginViewModel">
```

After (resolves the problem):

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
```

Comment: Yeah, you cannot really have both `x:Key` and  `DataType` because `x:Key` overrides the "implicitness" of the `DataType`. So if you `x:Key` you have to use your template with `ContentTemplate="{StaticResource LoginView}"`.

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed this was the only difference between your code and mine and tried to remove it and it worked. Thanks again for your patience and help!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue:

Comment: Yeah, if you want to reference it via key AND have it still work as the default DataTemplate for the type, then you can remove Key=..., create a second DataTemplate with BasedOn={x:Type ...} and the same DataType.

Answer (score 11):

WPF does not support implicit DataTemplates with `string` as the type identifier.

You need to use the [`x:Type` Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify your view model type:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">
    <views:LoginView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't solve my issue. I switched `DataType="vm:LoginViewModel"` with `DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}"`, but I still only see the "JollyFinance.ViewModels.LoginViewModel" string instead of my LoginView

Comment: Strange, with the x:Type it should work. It seems WPF is not able to find your DataTemplate. Are the `<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>` and the `<DataTemplate DataType="vm:LoginViewModel">` definied in the same file? Can you try to explicitly specify the DataTemplate? So try to change your `<DataTemplate x:Key="login">` and in the contentcontorl: `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource login}" ...` to see that the template is "visible" from your content control...

Comment: Yes, they are both in MainWindow.xaml. I have tried explicitly specify the DataTemplate to the ContentControl the way you have described, but still the same issue persists. The only difference it makes is instead of seeing "JollyFinance.ViewModels.LoginViewModel", I see "System.Windows.DataTemplate".

Comment: You are not correctly applied the contenttemaplte. The full code is like this `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource login}" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"/>` I guess you have tried: `<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource login}"/>` that is why you've gotten the "System.Windows.DataTemplate". Other that I was not able to repro this issue in an empty project. There the `DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}"` fixes the problem.

Comment: This does indeed work. If you want to edit your answer or create a new one, I will set it as answered. Also, out of curiosity, this was not mentioned in the post I have linked in my question, nor was it mentioned in most of the examples I have seen online. Is it because there was a change in the .net/WPF framework since those examples were written?

Comment: No, no this is not the solution this was just a test to figure out what could be the problem. With this `ContentTemplate="{StaticResource login}"` you will loose the ability to dynamically replace your `CurrentViewModel` and use a different view. So this is not yet the solution. Noting changed in WPF so the linked article should also work and also my answer about the `DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}"`...

Comment: I have found that on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.95).aspx): `The Content property of a ContentControl can be any type of object, such as a string, a UIElement, or a DateTime. When Content is set to a UIElement, the UIElement is displayed in the ContentControl. **When Content is set to another type of object, a string representation of the object is displayed in the ContentControl.**` It is normal then for it to be only a string in my window no?

Comment: The contentcontrol should use the datatemplate if it finds one. So it is not normal to display a string. Please check this simple example where your code is working with using my fix: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgzww3vn1ankg4r/WpfApplication1.zip?dl=0 `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:LoginViewModel}">`

Comment: Yes, your project works perfectly. I do not see the same behavior in your project.

Comment: I can't believe I have been using WPF for over a decade and this tiny detail never occurred to me.