# Best way to bind a set of same-type ViewModels to a TabControl in MVVM / WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an existing ViewModel and View in an MVVM project.  Effectively this View presents a collection of items in a particular, styled way.  I'll call this existing ViewModel "CollectionPresenter".

Up to now, this has been presented as as follows in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ns:CollectionPresenter />
</Grid>
```

Now, I want to have a dynamic collection of these "CollectionPresenter" view models made available ideally in a tab view.

My approach has been to define an observable collection of these "CollectionPresenters", creating them first on construction of the parent view model.  The XAML above then changed to look something like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding CollectionPresenters}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CollectionPresenterTitle}">
        </DataTemplate>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
         ... this is where things get confusing
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
<TabControl>
```

You can see above my problem is the ContentTemplate.

When I load this up, I get a tab control and it has as many tabs as my observable collection of "CollectionPresenter" objects.

However, the content of the tab control is always empty.

Is this approach correct - and is there a better way regardless?

EDIT:  ADDING SOME EXTRA THINGS TO MAKE IT CLEARER

I've tried the below, but it doesn't work.  The XAML with the Tab Control (the binding to "Things" works fine):

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Things}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:Thing}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThingName}" Width="200" Background="Blue" Foreground="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>    
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:Thing}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThingName}" Width="500" Height="500" Background="Blue" Foreground="White"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>  
</TabControl>
```

The definition for the "Things" observable collection (which is inside the templated parent (ParentObject) of the XAML with the tab control):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ThingsProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Things", typeof(ObservableCollection<Thing>), typeof(ParentObject), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Thing>)GetValue(ThingsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ThingsProperty, value); }
}
```

Stripped down version of the "Thing" view model:

```
public class Thing : ViewModelBase
{       
    public Thing()
    {
    }

    public void Initialise(ObservableCollection<Thing> things, string thingName)
    {            
        Things = things;
        ThingName = thingName;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ThingNameProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ThingName", typeof(string), typeof(Thing), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string ThingName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ThingNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThingNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might like to see my answer to the [WPF MVVM navigate views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views/19654812#19654812) question.

Comment: Thanks @Sheridan but it's not helped.  The issue I have is that the TabItem's ItemsSource contains a collection of view models - but when I define the TabControl.ItemTemplate and refer to a property of the view model using {Binding ....} it doesn't work - and the visual tree doesn't show the view models ... it just shows tab items, with the visual items in the ItemTemplate, but no reference to the actual item from the ItemsSource collection ...

Comment: Your method is flawed, which is why I provided you with a link on how to do it properly. With your method, you have to load all view models at once, which is a huge and unnecessary waste of RAM.

Comment: The view models need to be loaded up front since the tabs are purely to allow what *should* be on the screen all at once to be spread over 2-5 tabs (since there isn't physical room for them on a single tab).  Basically we don't want dynamic loading of view models, we want them all to be pre-loaded - but just tab-accessed on the screen.

Comment: The linked answer also shows you a solution to your problem too... I'll add an answer.

Comment: Ok, I did edit the question a few minutes ago anyway.  I've boiled it down to a problem whereby the objects in the "ItemsSource" collection are not presenting themselves to the data template I have defined for each tab item - and I guess I'm trying to (regardless of 'correctness' of approach) work out why this is happening ...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at my answer to the [WPF MVVM navigate views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views/19654812#19654812) question, you can see this:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:MainViewModel}">
    <Views:MainView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PersonViewModel}">
    <Views:PersonView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:CompanyViewModel}">
    <Views:CompanyView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, wherever we use an instance from one of these types in our application, these `DataTemplates` will tell the framework to display the related view instead.

Therefore, your solution is to simply *not* hard-code one single `DataTemplate` to the `TabControl.ItemTemplate` property, but to leave that blank instead. If you use multiple `DataTemplate`s *without* providing `x:Key` values, then they will implicitly be applied when each data object is to be rendered in the `TabControl`.

---

UPDATE >>>

Using these `DataTemplate`s should leave your `TabControl` looking like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Things}" />
```

I'm not sure why you're using a `TemplateBinding` there though as you don't need to define any new templates to get this working... therefore, you should be using a plain old `Binding` instead.

One other thing that you need to do is to use *different data types for each item in the collection that you want to display differently*. You could derive custom classes from your `Thing` class and so the collection could still be of type `ObservableCollection<Thing>`.

Comment: Our equiv. of your view (e.g. Views:CompanyView) consists of a ResourceDictionary which defines a style and control template for target type "Thing" ... does this approach still hold?

Comment: You only have a `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate` in your question, so I'm not really sure what you mean, but if you can put it into a `DataTemplate`, then yes, otherwise no... just try it out.

Comment: Yes I had simplified it for the sake of not writing a massive amount of code into the post.  My last comment on the original post holds though - the objects in the "ItemsSource" collection are not presenting themselves to the data template I have defined for each tab item, even if that tempate is the basic textbox ...

Comment: Although it actually solve my problem, I think that's because I didn't explain it in full.  I am going to upvote your answer as I think it is good nonetheless... in the end I overrode the tab control and achieved this.