# WPF Navigation using MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to follow the answer [provided in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views), but I must be missing something trivial.  I've defined my `DataTemplate`s as `App.xaml` as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:BlowerViewModel}">
        <v:BlowerView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HomeViewModel}">
        <v:HomeView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, in my `MainWindow.xaml` I've defined the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="App.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.UI.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Window>
```

The code for `MainViewModel` contains a property `CurrentView` and an `ICommand` so I can switch views.  Defined as follows:

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private BaseViewModel _currentView;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CurrentView = new HomeViewModel();
    }

    public BaseViewModel CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentView != value)
            {
                _currentView = value;
                RaiseChangedEvent("CurrentView");
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand SwitchView { 
        get {
            return new CommandHandler(() => SwitchBlower());
        }
    }

    protected void SwitchBlower()
    {
        CurrentView = new BlowerViewModel(); 
    }
}
```

In my `HomeView.xaml`, I have defined a button that links to the `MainViewModel` to execute the `SwitchView ICommand`.  This is shown below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.UI.View.HomeView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:App.UI.ViewModel"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>This is the homeview</TextBlock>
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SwitchView, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vm:MainViewModel}}, Mode=OneWay}" Content="Test" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I start the application it doesn't register the event, and clicking on the button does not fire the event to change the view. I've tried putting breakpoints in both the `ICommand get` and the function call itself.  At first, I thought maybe I needed to define `MainViewModel` in my data templates, but doing so results in the following error (even though the project builds fine)

> Can't put a Window in a style

Can anyone provide the missing piece I need to get this working?

Comment: AncestorType should be MainWindow not MainViewModel. MainViewModel is not a class that is part of the visual tree. At a cursory glance, everything else looks fine.

Comment: @LeeO. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as accepted.  Looks like it was a case of tunnel vision for me!  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: It's looks like you're all sorted now, well done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AncestorType should be MainWindow not MainViewModel. MainViewModel is not a class that is part of the visual tree.