# How can i manage the Navigation of views inside regions in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple regions inside Shell,
I have multiple views inside region,
I have multiple views inside view,
I didn't use frame or NavigationWindow elements in xaml files
So How can i navigate the current view to other view?
Or is there any way to manage this without NavigationService?

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views

Comment: Thanks for suggestion...I have  tried that one also but it can't gives proper fix for me. Again thanks for your attention.