# MVVM Open a view from Mainview with command

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view

I'm trying to open a view from my mainview in a button click command, I just need to know what i have to replace in my method GoToNewPage()

```
private DelegateCommand newPageCommand;

    public ICommand NewPage
    {

        get
        {

            if (newPageCommand == null)
            {
                newPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(GoToNewPage);
            }
            return newPageCommand;
        }
    }


    private void GoToNewPage()
    {
      //What i have to write there?
    }
```

Comment: It depends on the implementation. Advice - search for examples and you will find a lot of them. Also please take a minute and read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views

Answer (score -1):

```
private void GoToNewPage()
{
    var window = new ViewClassName();
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.