# vb.net - Can I load a wpf form into a canvas/grid control?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

I trying to see if its possible to load a form into a canvas or grid control in wpf with vb.net.

I'm not very familiar with WPF at all, usually working with Winforms more than anything else, however I need to take advantage of the far superior transparancy options offered by WPF for this current project, so need to see if I can crack this.

In Winforms, I'd normally have a panel (call it contentpanel or mainpanel etc) and then whenever I needed to I could easily load another form into that panel dynamically and keep everything neat and tidy in one form when presented to the user, so something like...

```
 dim newforminstance as form1
 newforminstance.toplevel = true
 newforminstance.topmost = false
 contentpanel.controls.add(newforminstance)
 newforminstance.show
```

That works a treat in Winforms; Is there a similar way to achieve this functionality in WPF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views

Comment: if you want to learn wpf ways after winforms, you canbenefit a lot from reading http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/ articles