# How can I open a page in the same frame when click a button in that frame in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a frame and there is page with 2 buttons in that frame. I want to open another page in that same frame when click a button on previous page. I know how to open the page when initializing the frame.

```
public partial class PnlTabs_SM : Window
{
    public PnlTabs_SM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frame_SM.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("SubPnlWelcomeTabs.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    } 
}
```

Here you can find the Page Code:

```
 public partial class SubPnlWelcomeTabs : Page
{
    public SubPnlWelcomeTabs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPurchaseRequistions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        
    }
}
```

the page which I want to open:

```
public partial class SubPnlPRTabs : Page
{
    public SubPnlPRTabs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

XAML Frame Code:

```
<Frame x:Name="frame_SM"
       x:FieldModifier="public"
       NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"
       Width="950" 
       Height="460"/>
```

I want to display the SubPnlPRTabs page in the same frame called "frame_SM" when click btnPurchaseRequistions

Kind consideration is highly appriciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add public method for changing page, e.g:

```
public partial class PnlTabs_SM : Window
{
    public PnlTabs_SM()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Navigate("SubPnlWelcomeTabs.xaml");
    } 

    public void Navigate(string page)
    {
        frame_SM.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(page, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

and call it from open pages:

```
public partial class SubPnlWelcomeTabs : Page
{
    public SubPnlWelcomeTabs()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPurchaseRequistions_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        var w = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<PnlTabs_SM>().First();
        w.Navigate("SubPnlPRTabs.xaml");
    }
}
```

You might also want to look at navigation based on DataTemplates: [WPF MVVM navigate views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654295/wpf-mvvm-navigate-views)